# Java: Adding up to 50 and going back down to 0

Tags: java

I'm creating a football game in Java.  Drive starts at 20 yard line and every time there is a play the yard line is updated.  So if the first play is a gain of 5 yards they would then be on the 25 yard line.  The problem is, say they are on the 49 yard line and they get a 10 yard play.  That should put them at the 41 yard line.  However, I have no idea how to make it do this.  The way I have my code right now, the ball would be on the 59 yard line, which doesn't exist in football.  Any suggestions please?

public void callPlays() {

```
System.out.println("Redskins begin drive on their own 20 yard line");

Random random = new Random();
Random yardsGained = new Random();
Random yardsLost = new Random();

int numberOfYards = 0; // yards gained on play
int lossOfYards = 0; // yards lossed on sack
int down = 1;
int yards = 10;
int totalYards = 0;
int yardLine = 20;


while (true) {

  if (down == 1) {
    System.out.println(down + "st and " + yards + " on the Redskins " +    
    yardLine + " yard line.");

  } else if (down == 2) {
        System.out.println(down + "nd and " + yards + " on the Redskins 
        " + yardLine + " yard line.");

  } else if (down == 3) {
        System.out.println(down + "rd and " + yards + " on the Redskins 
        " + yardLine + " yard line.");

  } else if (down == 4) {
        System.out.println("Redskins punt");
        break;
  } 

  numberOfYards = yardsGained.nextInt(11);
  lossOfYards = yardsLost.nextInt(11);

  String[] passCatchers = new String[6];

  passCatchers[0] = "DeSean Jackson";
  passCatchers[1] = "Pierre Garcon";
  passCatchers[2] = "Jamison Crowder";
  passCatchers[3] = "Jordan Reed";
  passCatchers[4] = "Matt Jones";
  passCatchers[5] = "Chris Thompson";

  int passCatcher = random.nextInt(passCatchers.length);

  String[] backs = { "Matt Jones", "Chris Thompson" };

  int runningBack = random.nextInt(backs.length);

  String[] plays = new String[7];

  plays[0] = "Cousins pass complete to " + passCatchers[passCatcher] + 
  " for " + numberOfYards + " yards.";

  plays[1] = "Handoff to " + backs[runningBack] + " along the left edge 
  for " + numberOfYards + " yards.";

  plays[2] = "Handoff to " + backs[runningBack] + " up the middle for "    
  + numberOfYards + " yards.";

  plays[3] = "Handoff to " + backs[runningBack] + " along the right  
  edge for " + numberOfYards + " yards.";

  plays[4] = "Screen pass to " + passCatchers[passCatcher] + " for " + 
  numberOfYards + " yards";

  plays[5] = "Kirk Cousins scrambles for " + numberOfYards + " yards";

  plays[6] = "Kirk Cousins sacked for " + "-" + lossOfYards + " 
  yards.";

        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int select = random.nextInt(plays.length);

        System.out.println(plays[select]);

        if (select == 6) {             
            yards += lossOfYards;
            totalYards -= lossOfYards;
            yardLine -= lossOfYards;
        } else {
            yards -= numberOfYards;
            totalYards += numberOfYards;
            yardLine += numberOfYards;
        }

        if(yards <= 0) {
            down = 0;
            yards = 10;
        }

        if(totalYards >= 80) {
            System.out.println("Touchdown!");
            break;
        }

        down++;

    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to abstract the football field to have yards from -50 to 50, with 0 being the center, and +-50 being the goal lines. This way, you have something that resembles the integers, around which computer programming language can be written easily.

When you go to convey information to a user, invoke a method to convert this into the domain specific language -- that is, that people expect a football field to be 0-50, 50-0.

So for example, if some event happens at -41, you can say that is "Team A 9 yard line", or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

The big issue here is that the "yard line" isn't merely a number.  There are two 40 yard lines, so if `yardLine` is 40, how do you know where you are on the field?

The "OO way" (tm) to do this would be to define a class that can represent both the yard line and which side of the field.  I won't give you the whole class, but here's a sketch of what it might look like:

```
public class YardLine {
    public YardLine(int yards, WhichTeam team) { ... }
    public void move(int yards, WhichTeam team) { ... }
    public String toString() { ... }
        // Could return something like "Skins' 25", "Opponents' 10", or 
        // maybe just "50-yard line" if that's where the ball is
}
```

`WhichTeam` would be something that represents either the Redskins or the other team.  You could simplify this by making it an `int` or a `boolean`, although I think an `enum` could lead to more readable code.  `move` means that the team moves the ball that many yards toward the opponent's goal (thus `move(-5,REDSKINS)` if they get sacked is more or less equivalent to `move(5,OPPONENTS)`).

As for implementing the class methods, my recommendation would be to keep just one instance variable that ranges from 0 to 100, and not worrying about which side of the field it's on until `toString` is called.  That would be much easier than trying to keep another variable that tells which side of the field it's on.  (So yeah, *internally*, the class may think the ball is on the 59-yard line.  But that's an implementation detail that is hidden from `callPlays()`.)  Having the variable range from -50 to 50 (as in Jameson's answer) is another possibility.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to accomplish what you want. If you want to stick to a solution that is close to your original code (i.e. without refactoring everything to be object oriented, which is admittedly the more canonical Java way to do it), one way to handle it might be to simply have two `yardLine` variables to track the line of scrimmage, one from the perspective of each team's end zone.

So, your code might start with something like:

```
int yardLine = 20;
int opponentsYardLine = 80;
```

`yardLine` would be 0 at your end zone and `opponentsYardLine` would be 0 at their end zone. At the 50 yard line, they would both be 50.

Every time there is a down, you'd need to update both variables, adding to one and subtracting from the other.

```
# make a +10 yard play
int play = 10
yardLine += play
opponentsYardLine -= play
```

If we consider the example in your question where we start at our 49 yard line and make a +10 yard play, `yardLine` would then be 59, which isn't what we call that location on the field. However, `opponentsYardLine` would be 41, which is what it's called.

When you print out where you are, you can handle separately the situation where `yardLine < opponentsYardLine`, `yardLine == opponentsYardLine == 50`, and `yardLine > opponentsYardLine`. This also gives you a place where you can modify the print statement so that instead of `" on the Redskins "` it can say the name of the opposing team.

Perhaps something like:

```
String teamSide;
int displayYardLine;
if(yardLine < opponentsYardLine) {
    displayYardLine = yardLine;
    teamSide = "our"; // or our team name
} else if(yardLine == opponentsYardLine) {
    displayYardLine = yardLine;
    teamSide = "the";
} else if(yardLine > opponentsYardLine) {
    displayYardLine = opponentsYardLine;
    teamSide = "the opponent's" // or their team name
}

System.out.println(down + "st and " + yards + " on " + teamSide + " " +    
displayYardLine + " yard line.");
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have decided to implement this is rather odd. There are many ways to do this. The best I could offer you with your current code is this. First thing is instead of having two separate variables ( lossOfYards and numberOfYards) create one (I.e changeInYards) then the functional (maybe not efficient) code is as follows.

```
while (changeInYards != 0){
    if (changeInYards < 0){
        totalYards--;
        if(totalYards > 50){
            yardLine++;
        }else{
            yardLine--;
        }
        changeInYards++;
    }else {
        totalYards++;
        if(totalYards > 50){
            yardLine--;
        }else{
            yardLine++;
        }
       changeInYards--;
    }
}
```

This code will check for every yard gained if the player is past the 50 yard line and what direction there are going. Based on that information we change the variables accordingly.

Answer (score -3):

`if(yardLine > 50) { yardLine = 100 - yardLine; }`

Comment: Well, yeah. That's true. One more variable is required to track which side of the 50 you're on, or the distance of the ball from the original end line.

Comment: Thank you everyone for replies.  Very helpful :)